# ssh installed but I get the error: Failed to start ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, services, openconnect

I have ssh and openconnect installed but when I proceed to start or stop the ssh service, I get the following error:

> Failed to start ssh.service: Unit ssh.service not found.

Also, when I try `sudo apt-get install ssh` I get the following:

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ncurses-term openssh-server openssh-sftp-server ssh-import-id
Suggested packages:
  ssh-askpass rssh molly-guard monkeysphere
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ncurses-term openssh-server openssh-sftp-server ssh ssh-import-id
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 193 not upgraded.
Need to get 640 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5.237 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Which I find confusing. If I do `which ssh`, I get:

```
/usr/bin/ssh
```

How can the binary be there if apt-get thinks the package is not installed?

Also, when calling `ssh <valid-IP-address>`, I get the following error:

> ssh: connect to host  port 22: No route to host

But if I use openconnect and connect to a VPN, ssh work without problems.

What am I missing? I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `ssh` binary, the SSH client, is provided by the `openssh-client` package, which is installed on your system.

The `ssh` service runs the SSH server, provided by the `openssh-server` package, which isn’t installed on your system.

The `ssh` package is a meta-package which installs both the client and the server.

Comment: Just installed that `ssh` meta package in my buster just for trying it out. Is it recent? +1

Comment: It used to be the main binary package; it became a transitional package in 2004, and its description was changed in 2007 to identify it as a meta-package.

Comment: Thanks! I have been using openssh-client and openssh-server directly for ages now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What would explain me not being able to connect with ssh without the vpn connection, then..?

Comment: @Kirjain that’s more likely to be network-related rather than contingent on the availability of the SSH service. I would guess you’re trying to connect to a host which isn’t reachable directly, but is reachable over your VPN.

Comment: @StephenKitt All right, thanks for your insight. I marked your question as the answer, and will look into the connectivity problem separately.

Comment: @Kirjain Here as corporate policy we only allow SSH over a VPN. I advise first of all, understanding the network design and security policies.

Answer (score 10):

Your SSH package/daemon/service is not installed.

For installing the SSH service on Ubuntu, you run:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

see [Packages - openssh-server - xenial](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/openssh-server)